# They found him at the base of the tree, his leg broken

Tags: sentence-construction

Someone wrote the following sentence:

> He fell off a tall tree, **his leg broken**.

a native speaker said that this sentence was not idiomatic because "one event followed the other"
and if "both conditions exist at the same time" one can say:

> They found him at the base of the tree, **his leg broken**.

Does this sentence sound natural?

Comment: Yes, the second sentence is perfectly fine and the first is not. In the second sentence "his leg broken" describes his state *when they found him*; in the first sentence it describes the action of how he broke his leg. The same words are not fulfilling the same function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> He fell off a tall tree, his leg broken.

This implies his leg was broken at the time he fell, not as a result of falling. Possibly something happened when he was in the tree that broke the leg, and the broken leg caused him to fall from the tree.

> They found him at the base of the tree, his leg broken.

This implies his leg was broken at the time he was found. It seems likely that it broke when he hit the ground at the end of his fall.